# R Network Package - node attributes

Tags: r, networking, package, visualization

I've recently started to learn R, with specific interest in network modeling applications.  I've made a sample dataset and would like to visualize it, eventually getting to rigorous statistical network analysis.

The example is a high school friendship network.  The node attributes are found in HS1_Node_Attributes.csv and the adjacency matrix is found in HS1_adjacency_matrix.  I'm able to visualize the network, though I'm having trouble with node attributes (characteristics of the people).  I'm using the network package.

The error I get is as follows:

Error in set.vertex.attribute(g, vertex.attrnames[[i]], vertex.attr[[i]]) : 
  Inappropriate value given in set.vertex.attribute.

I have cross-referenced my example with some tutorials online, along with the R Network package documentation.  The potential problem could have been the type of my attribute data frame, though I confirmed it was type list, which checks out.  So I'm not sure what the problem is.  Everything works fine (meaning I can successfully create a network object) if I don't take out node attributes (the `vertex.attr` and the `vertex.attrnames` arguments), showing me that the rest of the code is sound.  My code is below.

```
high_school1_attributes <- read.table("HS1_Node_Attributes.csv", header = TRUE, 
                     sep = ",")
high_school1_adj <- read.table("HS1_adjacency_matrix.csv", header = TRUE, 
                         row.names = 1, sep = ",")
adj1 <- as.matrix(high_school1_adj)

library("network")

high_school1_network <- network(adj1, vertex.attr = high_school1_attributes,
                            vertex.attrnames = colnames(high_school1_attributes),
                            directed = FALSE, hyper = FALSE, loops = FALSE, 
                            multiple = FALSE, bipartite = FALSE)
```

Comment: its great that you're here! for us to help you out, we need a reproducible example (as we don't have those CSVs).

Comment: at a minimum include head() or something to print an example of the high_school1_ structures and colnames

Answer (score 0):

You could be automatically converting strings to factors. I can recreate the error by doing:

```
high_school1_attributes <- read.csv(text=
        "Name,Color
        Kermit,green
        Piggy,pink
        Gonzo,blue")
high_school1_adj <- read.csv(text=
        ",From,To
        1,1,3
        2,3,2
        3,2,1",
    row.names = 1)
adj1 <- as.matrix(high_school1_adj)


library("network")

high_school1_network <- network(
        adj1,
        vertex.attr = high_school1_attributes,
        vertex.attrnames = colnames(high_school1_attributes),
        directed = FALSE, hyper = FALSE, loops = FALSE, 
        multiple = FALSE, bipartite = FALSE)
```

And can fix it by replacing the first statement with:

```
high_school1_attributes <- read.csv(text=
        "Name,Color
        Kermit,green
        Piggy,pink
        Gonzo,blue",
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Which you can see works by plotting:

```
library(igraph)
library(intergraph)

hs_graph <- asIgraph(high_school1_network)
plot(hs_graph, vertex.size=8,
    vertex.color=V(hs_graph)$Color,
    vertex.label=V(hs_graph)$Name,
    edge.arrow.size=0.25,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold)
```

Comment: is the answer that i gave here (similar question) correct? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64852237/r-creating-a-statnet-network-with-node-attributes