# R: creating a 'statnet' network with node attributes

Tags: r, graph, nodes, edges

I am following the examples over here on using the "statnet" library in http://personal.psu.edu/drh20/papers/v24i09.pdf.

The first example shows how to inspect a statnet network object in R:

```
library(statnet)
library(network)
 data("faux.magnolia.high") 
 fmh <- faux.magnolia.high 
summary(fmh)
```

In the above example, it seems here that the statnet network in this example already has "node attributes".

Using the statnet library, does anyone know if there is a way to directly create a network with node attributes from a data frame?

For example, if I have some data that looks like this:

```
mydata <-data.frame(

"source" = c("123","124","123","125","123"),
"target" = c("126", "123", "125", "122", "111"),
"color" = c("red","red","green","blue","red"),
"food" = c("pizza","pizza","cake","pizza","cake")
)
```

Suppose I had a pre defined list of node attributes:

```
Nodes <-data.frame(

"source" = c("123","124","125","122","111", "126"),

"Country" = c("usa", "uk", "uk", "usa", "uk", "usa")

)
```

I tried the following code:

```
net = network(mydata)
```

But I am not sure if this has created a network with the node attributes (color and food).

I also tried this, but it did not work:

```
mydata <-data.frame(

"source" = c("123","124","123","125","123"), "target" = c("126", "123", "125", "122", "111"), "color" = c("red","red","green","blue","red"), "food" = c("pizza","pizza","cake","pizza","cake") )

Nodes <-data.frame(

"source" = c("123","124","125","122","111", "126"),

"Country" = c("usa", "uk", "uk", "usa", "uk", "usa")

)

net<-network(mydata[,c[1:2])

edges <- as.sociomatrix(mydata[,c(3:4)],simplify=TRUE)

nodes <- as.sociomatrix(Nodes,simplify=TRUE)

final <- as.sociomatrix(list(net,edges,nodes))
```

Can someone please show me how to create a network with node attributes?

source: https://rdrr.io/github/statnet/network/man/as.sociomatrix.html

Thanks

Comment: Does this involve using the 'sociomatrix' command in R? https://www.mjdenny.com/Preparing_Network_Data_In_R.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this be the answer? https://igraph.org/r/doc/graph_from_data_frame.html

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(mydata, directed=TRUE, vertices=Nodes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Igraph is OK, but if you want to remain within the network package, that is statnet suite, you could do the following:

```
net<- as.network(mydata, matrix.type = "edgelist")
set.vertex.attribute(net, "color", as.character(mydata$color))
set.vertex.attribute(net, "food", as.character(mydata$food))
#To verify...
get.vertex.attribute(net, "color")
```

It seems that the set.vertex.attribute function does not accept factors, hence as.character()

If you have a lot of vertex attributes you could use "apply" to apply the set.vertex.attribute as a function over columns of a data frame with vertex attributes.

Generally, the materials (tutorials) for statnet suite from Michael Heaney were very useful to me (materials linked in the first bullet under the title "Summer Workshops"): http://michaeltheaney.com/teaching

Comment: Lucic : thank you for your reply! A question I had: mydata$color and mydata$food are "edge attributes". The "node attributes" is Nodes$Country. Could I change your code to : set.vertex.attribute(net, "Country", as.character(Nodes$Country)) .... set_edge_attr(net, "color", as.character(mydata$color))  ?

Comment: Lucic: Suppose if the variable type is not a "factor", could you write : set.vertex.attribute(net, "income", as.numeric(mydata$income)) ?

Comment: @Noob Yes, you could change the code simply. Function **set.edge.attribute** works in the same way as set.vertex.attribute. As for vector types in a data frame of attributes, you can always check their class with class(). I doubt you would have your income variable as a factor, but you can always check and transform it as you wrote, if necessary.

Comment: Lucic: Thanks! Would the first line of code you provided required to be changed? Instead of " net<- as.network(mydata, matrix.type = "edgelist") ", would it need to be changed to " net<- as.network(Nodes[,c(1:2)], matrix.type = "edgelist") " ? Thanks

Comment: @Noob No, it should not be changed. The first argument of as.network is data on network ties, in your case ('mydata') in edgelist form. To be more precise, only the first two columns ("source" and "target") are relevant for edgelists. You can retrieve the vertex names with _get.vertex.attribute(net, "vertex.names")_ Then, setting further vertex attributes as described above (**set.vertex.attribute(net, "country", as.character(Nodes$Country))**) means assigning attribute values to nodes in the order of the vector _get.vertex.attribute(net, "vertex.names")_.

Comment: Lucic: thanks again. I tried to put it all together and pasted my code over here https://shrib.com/#Kaliyah6M3LkQP (there wasnt enough room to paste my code in the comments). The code runs, but when I enter: get.vertex.attribute(net, "color") ... i get : NA NA NA NA NA  ... do you know what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: http://michaeltheaney.com/teaching his powerpoint slides are really good! thanks for recommending them!